# Can i change the position of an item in an object.(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an object as

```js
const details = {
  firstName: "Priya",
  age: 26,
  class: 12,
  Address: "UP",
  lastName: "Kumari"
}
```

Can I position the "lastName" key just after the "firstName" so that the new created object is :

```js
const updated = {
  firstName: "Priya",
  lastName: "Kumari",
  age: 26,
  class: 12,
  Address: "UP"
}
```

I tried few methods but read that positioning of object items is not possible

Comment: You can access it directly from the object. You don't need to apply anything for the position. Is there any specific use case that you are trying?

Comment: @mc-user I need to loop through the object to display each key and value in a table, where the lastName should come after firstName and its a huge list of item(this is just a small example) so i dont want to write each key statically.

Comment: Maybe you can map a key to a specific table column and access it using `data[column].` You already know the table columns and what needs to be displayed. Try to map like that.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the object to an array and then use the splice() function

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original answer with an example. You can format code when you use the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object, say `newDetails` based on the properties of the details object. We can use [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the firstName, lastName and all other properties. We'd then create the new object from these.

It's worth noting that we shouldn't rely too much on the order of object properties, since this can change.

```js
const details = { firstName: "Priya", age: 26, class: 12, Address: "UP", lastName: "Kumari"};

const { firstName, lastName, ...otherDetails} = details;

const newDetails = { firstName, lastName, ...otherDetails };

console.log('New details:', newDetails)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```